# 'Rollover'/'Roll over' in computer world

Tags: word-choice, computing

While Oxford Dictionary of English does not have definition of *rollover*, Wiktionary defines this word as "*a graphic element that changes its shape or colour when the cursor moves over it*"; in other terms, when we roll the trackball of a mouse over this element without having to click.

Also, it is common to use *rollover* as adjective and as verb, at least on internet.

Is this usage of *rollover* acceptable nowadays?

Since most people use now either optical mice or trackpads, has the term *rollover* become technically obsolete? If so, is there a better word?

Comment: In terms of alternatives, I think *mouseover* is or is becoming more common than *rollover*. I've also seen *hover text* used to describe HTML `<alt>` text (which is different but similar).

Comment: @zpletan - Thank you for the comment. I agree, *mouseover* is better than *rollover*.

Comment: The CSS selector for this action is [:hover](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

Answer (score 3):

The verb should be *roll over*, two words. That way you can conjugate it reasonably.

> When I rolled over the active element, nothing happened.

not

> *When I rollovered the active element, nothing happened.

For an adjective or noun, *rollover* as one word is fine.